# Strange result for an integral containing Meijer G-function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

The question is about Mathematica's result for the integral
$$ \int_0^\infty  \frac{16}{\pi^2} \left( \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} r^2 
%
G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(\frac{r^2}{4}\Bigg|
\begin{array}{l}
 0 \\
 0,0,-\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\right)^2 dr \,,$$
whereby the integrand will be denoted by $f(r)$ in the following. $G$ denotes the Meijer G-function (name of the corresponding Mathematica function: `MeijerG`).
According to Mathematica's `Integrate` function this integral is $1$. However, with `NIntegrate` one obtains the following results:
$$ \int_0^5 f(r) d r > 7 \,, $$
$$\int_0^{10} f(r) d r > 16 \,. $$
Furthermore Mathematica confirms that
$$ f(r) \geq 0 \,,\ \ \forall r \geq 0 $$
holds.
Using this together with the results from the numeric integrals one obtains
$$ \int_0^\infty f(r) d r = \int_0^{10} f(r) d r + \int_{10}^\infty f(r) d r
 > 16 + \int_{10}^\infty f(r) d r > 16 \,,$$
since the second integral has to be $\geq 0$ due to the non-negativity of the integrand.
This contradicts the result from Mathematica's `Integrate`, which says that the integral is $1$.

The **question** is: Where is the fault leading to the contradiction? Which statement is true?
(I would naively assume that `Integrate` is wrong in this case.)

*Note:* In the case one doubts the results for the numeric integrals from `NIntegrate`, one can plot the integrand. These plots make the results seem very plausible. A screenshot of the plots and of the used Mathematica commands can be found below.
Additionally, the used code is listed below for the case that some wants to test it.

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot of the Mathematica notebook where the integrals are evaluated]

**Used Mathematica code**

```
intgd[r_] := 16/\[Pi]^2*(1/4 Sqrt[\[Pi]] r^2 MeijerG[{{0}, {}}, {{0, 0}, {-(1/2)}}, r^2/4])^2
Integrate[intgd[r], {r, 0, Infinity}]
NIntegrate[intgd[r], {r, 0, 5}]
FullSimplify[intgd[r] >= 0, Assumptions -> {r >= 0}]
GraphicsRow[{Plot[intgd[r], {r, 0, 20}], Plot[intgd[r], {r, 0, 50}]}]
```

The used Mathematica version is 12.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

intgd[r_] := 
 16/π^2*(1/4 Sqrt[π] r^2 MeijerG[{{0}, {}}, {{0, 0}, {-(1/2)}}, 
      r^2/4])^2

lim = Limit[intgd[r], r -> Infinity]

(* 16/π^2 *)
```

For larger values of `r`, arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision is required for the `Plot`

```
Plot[intgd[r], {r, 0, 50},
 WorkingPrecision -> 30,
 PlotRange -> All,
 GridLines -> {None, {lim}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[1]]]
```

[image]

An alternate representation of the integrand for `r > 0` is

```
intgd2[r_] = intgd[r] // FunctionExpand // Simplify[#, r > 0] &

(* (16 r^2 (CoshIntegral[r] Sinh[r] - Cosh[r] SinhIntegral[r])^2)/π^2 *)

intgd[r] == intgd2[r] // FullSimplify[#, r > 0] &

(* True *)
```

For this alternate representation, even greater precision is required in the `Plot`

```
Plot[intgd2[r], {r, 0, 50},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50,
 PlotRange -> All,
 GridLines -> {None, {lim}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[1]]]
```

[image]

As expected, the integral on `{0, Infinity}` does not converge

```
Integrate[intgd2[r], {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

Comment: So, this is a nice way to show that `Integrate[intgd[r], {r, 0, Infinity}]` produces an incorrect result. This implies that Mathematica's `Integrate` has a bug here, right? 
(And thanks for showing how to plot the integrand adequately!)